# Swift Search ALL in tableview including table view cell details

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just new to Swift. I have a table view in view controller  including 4 table view cells. I want to create a search bar that can search all attributes including the 4 table cells such as label name of table row, status, time, request name. I have been researching many search tutorials but it only teach to search one attribute which is label name only instead of status, time and request name.

Is there any guide or tutorials to follow? thanks for your time for reading.

```
//This is what i edit, because i want it to search all attributes 
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filtered.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array1 = arrStatus + arrProcessName
    let array = (array1 as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
    filtered = array as! [String]
    tableView?.reloadData()
}

//This is without edit according to online tutorial, it seems like it only can search one attributes
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filtered.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (arrStatus as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
    filtered = array as! [String]
    tableView?.reloadData()
}




 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    removeProgressBar()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryCustomCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

    if self.searchCtrler.isActive {
    //In here, the value will be overrides by the search text, 
    //the search cannot be perform because it just 
    //replaced the label instead of searching. 
        cell.lbl_status.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.lbl_request_name.text = arrProcessName[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_requested_by.text = "Requested by: " + arrRequestedBy[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_creation_time.text = arrCreationTime[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_status.text = arrStatus[indexPath.row]

        switch arrStatus[indexPath.row] {
            case "Completed", "Approved":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_approved")
            case "Running", "Processing", "Pending":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_pending")
            case "Denied", "Rejected":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_reject")
            case "Error":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_terminated")
            case "Retracted":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_retracted")
            default:
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You only need to modify the search filter by adding more requirement to it, post your search string code and your object here so people can help you

Comment: FYI - you don't search the table view cells. You search the data in the data model used by the table view.

Comment: @Tj3n here are the code i put. i wish to search the process name and the status at one search bar.

Comment: @rmaddy hi, thanks for commenting, is there any guide i can refer to?

Comment: Your code look bad...why dont you combine your 4 array into 1 array of objects? With code like this, search result will be resulting into very wrong arrays, like array 1 have 2 match and array 2 have 1 match

Comment: @Tj3n thanks, i will try to combine it.